# Sensor to check if door is locked

Tags: arduino, sensor, power-electronics, piezo, piezoelectricity

I’m taking a subject of entrepreneurship and we have to present an idea to put in the market. My group thought about a keychain with a little light that warns us if we locked our front door or forgot. In case we don't lock, the light of the keychain is red. Otherwise the light will be green. We don’t have a deep understanding of electronics, but from what I searched I think the best way to do this would be with a piezoelectric sensor installed in the lock, so that when the door latch goes into the cavity, the sensor will be activated. I probably also need a arduino, right? To receive the information of the sensor. My question is: what else do I need to send that information to the keychain? How can that be done?

What are the main components to do something like this?

If anyone could explain me just the basics, it would be a big help already. Thanks.

Comment: The most reliable would be to design a special lock.

Comment: There are a ton of question you need to answer here... Like how far away it needs to work, if the LED needs to change colour if the door is unlocked by some other means when you are miles away.. and on and on... This also sound more like a job for a cell-phone app. Voting to close as too broad sorry.

Comment: Just making a sound (like an alarm) for a few seconds every time the door closes irrespective of whether it locks or is locked or unlocked is enough to remind anyone leaving through the door that it is potentially unlocked. It also doubles as a fake burglar alarm in case anyone is walking by and hears the sound it makes when you exit.

Comment: Actually microcontroller is not needed at all. If your requirement is just blinking an led when door is locked.

Comment: For a sensor, a microswitch or just an inductor (used as a metal detector) is probably a better choice.

Comment: I'm not sure a piezoelectric sensor is what you want at all. As a sensor, those are typically used to sense vibration. It may be difficult to determine the state of the lock that way. Also, your question is a bit too open-ended for here. As a single, answerable question, instead of asking us to start a project for you.

Comment: been looking at a few solutions, check out locksure.co.uk, new company but with a very simple solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You probably need an Arduino, to check with a sensor if the door is locked or not. You could use a sensor depending on what you kind is best.

The Arduino would receive / process the signal from the sensor (which is probably near/connected to the lock).

Than you need some kind of rF/wifi or other wireless shield or component to send it to the key.

Your key need to be able to receive this, which may need another Arduino. I would not opt for an Uno since these are way too big. Even a Micro can be already big as a 'key' with intelligence.